# R: Subscript Out of Bounds, Execution Halted

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to follow the instructions over here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/parcoord.html

```
 library(MASS)
   a = rnorm(100,10,10)
    b = rnorm(100,10,5)
    c = rnorm(100,5,10)
    d = as.matrix(a,b,c)
    
     parcoord(d[, c(3, 4, 2)], col = 1 + (0:149)%/%50)
```

It produces the following error:

```
    Error in d[, c(3, 4, 2)] : subscript out of bounds
    Calls: parcoord -> apply
    Execution halted
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Is it also possible to label the axis and put a title on the plot?

Thanks

Comment: I know the above is a good example, but it's good to avoid naming variables 'c', lest they get confused with function `c()`. If you accidentally remove the variable, the call will return the function, rather than an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your subscript is out of bounds

The subscript is `[ ,c(3,4,2)]`

Out of bounds means that you're indexing columns that don't exist. This is because `d` is a column vector - a matrix with only one column. This is happening because you're using `as.matrix` incorrectly.

You could make a three column matrix with: `d <- matrix(c(a, b, c), ncol = 3)`, but even then your subscript won't work, because your subscript is looking for column four.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your code and unfortunately the same error persists:  library(MASS)
   a = rnorm(100,10,10)
    b = rnorm(100,10,5)
    c = rnorm(100,5,10)
  d <- matrix(c(a, b, c), ncol = 3)

  parcoord(d[, c(3, 4, 2)], col = 1 + (0:149)%/%50)

Comment: Oh yes I see now - even with 3 cols you'd be indexing OOB, because one of your indeces is 4. What are you trying to do? Because in my example `d[ , c(1,2,3)]` would just return `d`.

Comment: I am trying to follow this example here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/parcoord.html .... but with some artificially created data

Comment: I suggest that you learn a little about dimensions and indexing before trying to do this. This may help: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/

Comment: The gist of it is that you're making a matrix with 1 column and then you're passing 'just the third, fourth and second columns' of that matrix as an argument to `parcoord`